# Angular application, generated webpage and integration

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, request, token

I have a single page angular application with injected views and a generated webpage (pgBadger). My application make an http request to get the pgBadger html.

The thing is that I cannot inject this html since I am in a single page application (I cannot have the pgBadger page inside my angular page).

So I will need another page for pgBadger. I tried a link like this:

```
<a href="/restricted/pgBadger/{{selectedCluster}}"></a>
```

Unfortunately I have a token base authentication system on my Nodejs server, so
the response is Unauthorized. I usually add the appropriate header in my request through the angular http interceptors.

It looks like there is no property to add headers in either **a** or **form** tag.

I am stuck at the moment, any suggestions are very welcome.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Small note, not really relating to your question but you should use ng-href.    Ex. `<a ng-href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}">link1</a>`   
More info in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref).

Comment: You could add the token in the querystring and parse it serverside, then put it in your headers.

Comment: You could also make a Angular directive that get the html with ajax, and replace the content of your directive with the html page.

Comment: Hi, Looks like I have no choice but to add the token in the querystring. It's quite ugly but it works... Fortunately the querystring is protected by the ssl protocol but the user should not see it IMO...